# how to consume a linq store expression?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, enums

Using entity framework. Was trying to convert a value from db to its corresponding enum type. Sadly this failed:

```
var abc = (from x in db.FooEntities select new { EnumValue = Enum.Parse(typeof(SqlDbType), x.ColumnType }).ToList();
```

It said something like linq to entities doesn't understand how to process Enum.Parse. I knew I had to do something with creating an expression, and even went ahead and did something like this.

```
Expression<Func<FooEntity, SqlDbType>> GetDbType()
{
    return p => (SqlDbType)Enum.Parse(typeof(SqlDbType), p.ColumnType);
}
```

Now how to consume this?

I've tried something like:

```
var k = GetDbType.Compile();
var abc = (from x in db.FooEntities select new { EnumValue = k(x), x.ColumnType }).ToList();
```

It still gives error saying,

> The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities.

Comment: You must convert it locally.

Comment: I don't have anything against the "local" approach, but I am curious to learn that store expression approach.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the issue with the first statement:

```
var abc = (from x in db.FooEntities
           select new
           {
               EnumValue = Enum.Parse(typeof(SqlDbType), x.ColumnType)
           }).ToList();
```

is that it was attempting to perform the `select` at the database level. Changing that statement to this:

```
var abc = (from x in db.FooEntities select x).ToList()
           .Select(x => new
           {
               EnumValue = Enum.Parse(typeof(SqlDbType), x.ColumnType)
           }).ToList();
```

would solve that error.